# jQuery AJAX request returns object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, typeahead

I have the following AJAX request:

```
$(function(){
    $("#MPrzezn").typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 3
      },
      {
            name: 'test',
            displayKey: 'value',
            source: function(query, process){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'sprawdzKraj.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'query=' + query,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                async: true,
                success: function(data){

                    process(data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }   
        });
    });
```

... and the following php on backend:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
$user = new User(); //current User
if($user->isLoggedIn()){
    if(isset($_POST['query'])){
        $query = $_POST['query'];
        $delegacja = new Delegacja();
        $dataListaDelegacji = $delegacja->listujMiasta($query);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $json_response = json_encode($dataListaDelegacji);
        echo $json_response;
    }

} else {
$isLoggedIn = false;
$smarty->assign("userid","",true);
$smarty->assign("isLoggedIn",$isLoggedIn,true);
Redirect::to('login.php');

}
```

The php script returns a proper json:

```
[{"ID":"66","IDKraju":"117","NazwaMiasta":"Inowroc\u0142aw","MiastoTlumaczenie1":null,"MiastoTlumaczenie2":null},
{"ID":"251","IDKraju":"117","NazwaMiasta":"\u015awinouj\u015bcie","MiastoTlumaczenie1":null,"MiastoTlumaczenie2":null},
{"ID":"2222","IDKraju":"74","NazwaMiasta":"Rhinow","MiastoTlumaczenie1":null,"MiastoTlumaczenie2":null},
{"ID":"3508","IDKraju":"94","NazwaMiasta":"San Bernardino","MiastoTlumaczenie1":null,"MiastoTlumaczenie2":null}]
```

The picture below shows how the json is being picked up by browser:

[There are 4 cities that match the query - each object is a city entry](https://flic.kr/p/oe4rbK)

My goal is to pass values of "NazwaMiasta" to a typeahead input, but I get "undefined" entries. I tried different things but it always keeps showing undefined like this:

[Red arrows show all 4 json nodes](https://flic.kr/p/nUN4Vn)

I hope I described my problem well. I understand that I'm pretty close, but I cannot find the solution myself. I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: How are you putting your entries into your HTML?

Comment: There is something wrong in `process(data);` part.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problematic part. For now I would just like to display a proper output in browser console. The best would be if someone could tell me how to pass json to typeahead in a right way. process(data); part I took from this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0H6myhWkfA video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put right `displayKey` value!

**insted of :**

```
displayKey: 'value',
```

**set :**

```
displayKey: 'NazwaMiasta',
```

**EDIT :**

**Detailed explanation** : When you return data via ajax call, `typeahead` doesn't know what value to display. So you must set where is value for that key. Your return array of object that have structure like this :

```
['key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2',...]
```

By setting ie `'key1'` , `typeahead` knows how to access value ie :

```
currentElement['key1']...
```

and than put that value to html.

Comment: `facepalm` Thank you that's the bit I was missing. :)